# Why does Docker call every machine Moby?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have noticed that whenever I create a new Dockerfile and:

`RUN FROM ubuntu:latest` or if I run the following command:

`docker run -it ubuntu bash` and then do:

`uname -a`, the result is always something like the following:

`Linux 5d0eab7d2f8e 4.9.36-moby #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 15:29:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Shouldn't the result be `Ubuntu-16.04` for `uname -r`?  Why does it say Moby instead of Ubuntu?

Comment: What's your OS to run Docker? MacOS or Linux?

Comment: This has something to do with the kernel OS also on which docker is running. On my vagrant VM inside same image i get `Linux vagrant 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. So yes it will be different only based on Host OS and docker version as well

Comment: @HaomingZhang, its on MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker container shares the kernel of the host OS, so when you call `uname -r` in a Ubuntu container, this command will return the info of host OS's kernel.

In your case, the host OS is MacOS. Since Docker needs a Linux kernerl and cannot use MacOS's kernel directly, Docker for Mac will try to create a HyperKit VM with Linux kernel (which called Moby Linux) to run the containers. So in this situation, the `uname -r` command will output the kernel info of Moby Linux.

For more details, please check Docker for Mac doc: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment

Comment: I have a program that requires the kernel to be a linux kernel, and it uses 'uname -r' to verify that. So if you have a linux container running ontop of MacOS (Moby), then this breaks any such concept of virtualization for such programs (or basically it means such programs cannot run inside containers).  Is there any workarounds for this?  (aside from requesting the maintainers of the program to modify the program's code itself)

Comment: @jerseybean I can't figure out any solution, seems like the program was designed for bare metal environment. You probably could create a question on SO with your comments, but I doubt that there has any workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

`4.9.36-moby` is the kernel release. The kernel is the one piece that is shared between the "host" and all containers. So you're running a Ubuntu container, but the kernel is from the "host".

Since you're on macOS the "host" is actually a linux VM run by Docker for Mac. That VM runs a kernel flavour called `moby`. I believe you can learn more about that kernel here: https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit